# jQuery Ajax request only works for single form submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am very new to jQuery and Ajax, so I put together a little system to see if I could produce a form with various features that are new to me, in hopes that I can use the techniques in future. It is a simple form which for submitting name, last name, email and phone no.

Everything works fine when you fill out the form and submit, and the response works fine. However, after the response message disappears and the form's fields are cleared, entering new data and submitting the form results in the ajax request executing successfully, but nothing is sent to the action file, as the response area (where the response message would show up normally) is expanded as if there is a message, but nothing is displayed. I am not sure how I can better illustrate my problem so hopefully somebody can see from the code:

```
<div id="wrap">

<div id="response">
    <span></span>
    <div id="ri1"></div>
    <div id="ri2" class="r_user"></div>
</div>

<span class="wraptitle">Form Standard</span>

<form method="post" action="process.php" id="mainform" name="mainform">
<table width="605" cols="3" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="155">
        First Name
        <br /><span class="error" id="fname_error"></span>
        </td>
        <td width="450" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="155">
        Second Name
        <br /><span class="error" id="sname_error"></span>
        </td>
        <td width="450" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="secondname" id="secondname" class="input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="155">
        Email address
        <br /><span class="error" id="email_error"></span>
        </td>
        <td width="450" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="emailaddr" id="emailaddr" class="input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="155">
        Phone Number
        <br /><span class="error" id="phoneno_error"></span>
        </td>
        <td width="450" colspan="2"><input type="text" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" class="input" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="155"></td>
        <td width="390"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form" class="input button" /></td>
        <td width="60" id="loader"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
```

process.php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['firstname'])
&&!empty($_POST['secondname'])
&&!empty($_POST['emailaddr'])
&&!empty($_POST['phoneno']))
{
    $response_array = array(
    'status'  => 'success',
    'message' => 'Congratulations, everything went fine.');

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode($response_array));
}
else
{
    $response_array = array(
    'status'  => 'fail',
    'message' => 'Massive Fail.');

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode($response_array));
}
```

jQuery (last thing before `</body>`)

```
$(document).on('submit','#mainform',function(e)
{
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');

    var form      = $(this);
    var post_url  = form.attr('action');
    var is_error  = false;

    $('#loader', form).html('<img src="load_big_grey.gif" border="0" width="48" height="15" style="margin:6px auto;display:block;" />');

    var firstname  = $('#firstname').val();
    var secondname = $('#secondname').val();
    var emailaddr  = $('#emailaddr').val();
    var phoneno    = $('#phoneno').val();
    var post_data  = 'firstname='+firstname+'&secondname='+secondname+'&emailaddr='+emailaddr+'&phoneno='+phoneno;

    $('.error').attr('style','display:none;');

    if(firstname==''){
        $('#fname_error').html('Required field').attr('style','display:block;');
        is_error = true;}

    // More client-side validation as above

    if(is_error)
    {
        $('#loader', form).html('');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: post_url,
            data: post_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function(ret)
                    {
                        if(ret != '')
                        {
                            /* Dealing with the server response */
                            var m_status  = ret.status;
                            var m_message = ret.message;
                            var empty_fld = true;
                            $('#loader', form).html('');

                            // THIS IS THE PART THAT DISPLAYS AN APPROPRIATE RESPONSE
                            if(m_status=='success')
                            {   $('#response').removeClass().addClass('r_pos');
                                $('#ri1').removeClass().addClass('r_check');}
                            else
                            if(m_status=='fail')
                            {   $('#response').removeClass().addClass('r_neg');
                                $('#ri1').removeClass().addClass('r_cross');
                                empty_fld = false;}

                            $('#response span').html(m_message);                            
                            $('#response').css('display','block');

                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                $('#response').fadeTo(500,0);
                                setTimeout(function()
                                {
                                    $('#response').css('display','none');
                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                    if(empty_fld)
                                    {
                                        $('#firstname').val('');
                                        $('#secondname').val('');
                                        $('#emailaddr').val('');
                                        $('#phoneno').val('');
                                    }
                                },500);
                            },4000);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /* The response from the server was undefined */
                            $('#loader', form).html('');
                            $('#response').removeClass().addClass('r_neg');
                            $('#response span').html('There was a problem communicating with the server!');
                            $('#ri1').removeClass().addClass('r_cross');
                            $('#response').css('display','block');
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                $('#response').fadeTo(500,0);
                                setTimeout(function()
                                {
                                    $('#response').css('display','none');
                                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                                },500);
                            },4000);
                        }
                    }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

(Kinda feel like I shouldn't have included as much.. :P)
I have looked around and have seen some things on rebinding events (which I think I've done by using on() instead of submit()) and a few other mentions of things I could try but nothing seems to have worked. Your help is much appreciated! Luke

Comment: what exactly is wrong (other than nothing is showing in your response div?) have you added an error handler to the ajax request to see whether or not it is failing? have you looked in the console to see if the request is being sent, and if so, what is being sent and what is being returned?

Comment: You aren't disabling the submit button correctly. you should be using .prop and a boolean value rather than .attr and .removeAttr

Comment: @KevinB - I added an error handler to display a simple message in the event of an error, and it is not triggered. The fact that the response area is "enlarged" must mean that the success function has been triggered because that is where the response is handled? I am unsure what you mean by console also, if you wouldn't mind explaining?

Comment: @KevinB and the submit button cannot be the issue as it still allows me to submit surely?

Comment: the submit button may not be **the** issue, but if you don't change to .prop it will become **a** issue later.

Comment: I have replaced all instances of the submit button disablement with what you suggested:
`$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);`
`$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);`
Functionality has remained the same and the problem persists unfortunately. How does it become an issue later?

Comment: It won't properly disable or enable the button after the first time in some browsers

Comment: I used firebug to see if anything unusual was going on, but the second ajax request goes through fine (as in everything is the same as the first), and the response comes back exactly the same. So presumably, it is something to do with my processing of the response maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the success function:

```
success: function(ret, textStatus)
         {
             console.log(ret);
             console.log(textStatus);
             ...
         }
```

I discovered that there was no problem with the response from the server and it was submitting and responding perfectly and in the manner I was expecting. I cannot directly identify what the issue was, but by adding a wrapper to my response section and just using .html() to update it instead of toggling classes, I have my desired result:

```
<div id="rwrap">
    <div id="response">
        <span></span>
        <div id="ri1"></div>
        <div id="ri2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var m_status  = ret.status;
var m_message = ret.message;
var empty_fld = true;
$('#loader').html('');

if(m_status=='success')
{
    $('#rwrap').html('<div id="response" class="r_pos"><span>'+m_message+'</span><div id="ri1" class="r_check"></div><div id="ri2" class="r_user"></div></div>');
}
else if(m_status=='fail')
{
    $('#rwrap').html('<div id="response" class="r_neg"><span>'+m_message+'</span><div id="ri1" class="r_cross"></div><div id="ri2" class="r_user"></div></div>');
    empty_fld = false;
}
```

Thanks to those who contributed!

Answer (score 0):

There are many things currently not really good with your code. I will list them here, so that you can fix them.

- The `mainform` is there the whole time. Attach the event handler directly to the form

  `$('#mainform').submit(function(event) {
      // your code
  });`
- Do not change the enable/disable state of the button with `attr`. Use `prop` instead.
- Use jQuery's css commands to add or remove css properties. See [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- The success callback function expects three parameters (data, textStatus, jqXHR). Use them:

  `success: function(ret, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // your code
  }`
- Use proper indentation to see scope of statements.

More specifically place the else and the connected if on one line to see it's meening.

```
if(m_status=='success')
{   
    $('#response').removeClass().addClass('r_pos');
    $('#ri1').removeClass().addClass('r_check');
}
else if(m_status=='fail') {   
    $('#response').removeClass().addClass('r_neg');
    $('#ri1').removeClass().addClass('r_cross');
    empty_fld = false;
}
```

If this bunch of problems are fixed, you can look into the actual problem if it still occurs.

Comment: I am using .prop as per Kevin's advice, just forgot to update the code and I am using .on() instead of .submit() to take advantage of the event rebinding, for multiple submissions. Everything else you've mentioned is a subjective view on how I've structured my code